# How to check quality of vermicompost?

Tags: identification, compost, vermicomposting

I know it must be really hard without proper equipment to check the quality of vermicompost, but is there, still, another way to test the quality?

To me, this doesn't look like vermicompost at all. It feels like soil mixed with some white seeds-like stuff.

They were all black in the bag it came in and when I applied it as a topsoil and watered it, most of the "castings" went from black to light brown and pale yellow. Is this casting drying out in sun or it is some other cheap material? How do I know it is real worm casting?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good worm castings should be black or brown. It is sometimes referred to as 'black gold'. The exact colour will depend on what they feed their worms. There should be nothing left in it.  It should not be sold until everything in it has been digested by the worms.   Imagine insect droppings and how small they are.  Or imagine very miniature mice scat.   It should well digested food poop.

It appears this company is not thinking about what they feed their worms.  If they wanted to make fast compost to sell at market the quickest they would be feeding them foods that are easy to digest like leafy vegetables. Instead they are feeding their worms the same matter that is hard for our much larger digestive tracts to break down.

This is crap! Not the crap you want.

Comment: So my guess was right. This is a total waste of money. I noticed it as soon as the casts lost color.